# Why 2 Different JSON Results with String Parameter Search using RestSharp?

Tags: json, restsharp

If I hard code the band name in my client request with RestSharp I get the results I expect.  If I pass in the String I get a different result set.  I checked the url it formed and they are the same.  Any ideas?  I don't use both, I will comment one out and use the other for testing this scenario.

```
 ArtistInfoResponse IMusicRepository.GetArtistResponse(string artistName)
    {
        var client = new RestClient($"https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:{artistName}");
        // returns this as url https://localhost:44343/Home/ArtistInformation?artistName=Dave%20Matthews%20Band

        var client = new RestClient($"https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:\"Dave Matthews Band\"");
        // returns this in url https://localhost:44343/Home/ArtistInformation?artistName=Dave%20Matthews%20Band
       
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            // Deserialize the string content into JToken object
            var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(response.Content);

            // Deserialize the JToken object into our ArtistInfoResponse Class
            return content.ToObject<ArtistInfoResponse>();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What are the results you're getting?

Comment: How does your Restclient completely rewrite the url? Ie totally different path and query?

Comment: and the quotes `\"` you have in the second query do make a difference. At least for deezer. Because if you search search for `https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:%22Dave%20Brubeck%22` vs `https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:Dave%20Brubeck` you will get different results

Comment: I get Dave Matthews Band results with all songs performed by the band when I hard code it with \".  I get Dave Matthews Band Karaoke results with songs artists being varied.

Comment: @derpirscher I debugged and looked at what the new RestClient was using with each method and you are correct.  I want the %22 to enclose my string.   I am searching for a way to add this programmatically to users search string.

Comment: Not sure if this would be frowned upon so any mentors out there to chime in?  I am using this now to ensure quotes for the search result I want from Deezer.                                                                                            artistName = (char)34 + artistName + (char)34;

Comment: But you already know how to add quotes. You are doing it in your second request. Just replace the constant with a template placeholder?